# Verificar se um valor está dentro de um array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

gostaria de fazer o seguinte: O usuário insere o seu CEP e um campo `input` e o valor que ele inserir dentro deste campo queria comparar se está na faixa de CEP (01000 a 19999) do estado de SP.

Minhas dúvidas:

**1ª -** No caso eu teria que montar um array com os números de 01000 a 19999?

**2ª -** Como eu faria para saber se o valor do inserido no `input` contém no array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### JS

```
var cep = '13426000';

if(arrayCeps.indexOf(cep) > -1){
   console.log('Tem no Array');
}
```

### jQuery

```
if($.inArray(cep, ArrayCeps) > -1){
   console.log('Tem no Array');
}
```

### PHP

Com `in_array($valor, $array)` você verifica valor.

```
$cep = '13426000';

if(in_array($cep, $arrayCeps){
   echo "Tem no Array";
}
```

Com o `array_key_exists($chave, $array)` verifica chaves.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta cara, mas eu tenho que fazer tudo isso em javascript/jquery, não consigo usar PHP. :(

Comment: Perdão, não reparei a tag. Vou editar.

Comment: Show de bola, fiz um teste aqui e funcionou muito obrigado!

Em relação a primeira pergunta, eu terei que listar todos os CEP's no array ou tem temo comparar só declarando o inicio e fim da faixa?

Comment: Tem que colocar todos no Array. Mas você não tem uma base de dados, uma tabela com os ceps ?

Comment: Não se consigo acessar pela api dos correios essa faixa, se não terei que fazer manualmente, mas de qualquer forma obrigado já ajudou muito!

Comment: Achei um site muito interessante que vai me ajudar!

https://viacep.com.br/